# Calculate average of tensor and use this value as the tensor value

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, average

I don't have good knowledge about Tensors so forgive me if this is a silly question.

I am trying to use Lambda layer from Keras to add a special layer for my model.
I want this layer to calculate the mean value of the tensor and I want this mean value to be used as the tensor value.

To make it clearer, this is what I need but in numpy, I don't know how to do it with tensor:
(using NumPy is not working with tensors)

```
   colInput ## this should be my tensor
   avg = np.mean(colInput)
   colInput =[avg for n in range(colInput.shape[0])]
```

I did try the following:

```
avg = tf.reduce_mean(colInput)
```

I also did try :

```
avLayer= Lambda(lambda x: tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=1, keepdims=False))(visible)
```

where visible has my colInput as input layer but I couldn't manage to make the result set for each element in the tensor, and use this new tensor.

My tensor shape is (?,1,27)
and I want it to have this 27, but they will be equal to the average value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: so if your input tensor is `[[1, 2, 3, 4]]`, you want the output to be `[[2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5]]`?

Comment: yes, that's true

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but let me know-

```py
xx = tf.constant([1., 0., 1., 0.])
tf.expand_dims(tf.repeat(tf.reduce_mean(xx), xx.shape[0]), axis=1)
```

Output would be

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0.5],
       [0.5],
       [0.5],
       [0.5]], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: Thanks Sai, This has the same concept that I need, but here your data shape is (4,), 

Could you help me how is this works for data shape (?,1,27), please?

Comment: `In[56]:tf.reshape(tf.repeat(tf.reduce_mean(xx), xx.shape[0]), [1,1,4])`  `Out[56]: <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]]], dtype=float32)>` this is extension of the example you see above, I think you could replce the reshape dimesnions to [1,1,27] to suite your needs